# How to clear a string in C

Tags: c

Is there a way in C to clear out my choice variable, so that on every loop it could be reused as a string variable input because each time I run the loop it works the first time through then doesn't take another input?

```c
char choice [255];
while (strcmp(choice,"logout")!=0) {
    memset(choice, 0, strlen(choice));
    printf("what would you like to do?\n");
    printf("1 - login\n");
    printf("2 - who\n");
    printf("3 - Lookup\n");
    printf("4 - logout\n");
    scanf("%s",choice);

    if(strcmp(choice,"login")==0){
        /* send server ip and player id*/
        printf("logging you in...");
    }

    if(strcmp(choice,"who")==0) {
        /* send server ip and player id*/
        printf("fetching all available players...");
    }

    if(strcmp(choice,"lookup")==0) {
        /* send server ip and player id*/
    printf("Who are you looking for?");
    }
}
```

Comment: Other than the case error in your "Lookup" vs "lookup", your code seems to work for me. But, to clear the string (you shouldn't need to, by the way, as the `scanf` will overwrite what's there), you can just use `strcpy(choice,"");`. Is there some other code you're not showing that would change things in your loop?

Comment: ... but, to add a level of potential debugging check the return value of `scanf` - that will tell you how many items were successfully read in (should be 1).

Comment: OK - Just noticed: On your *first* run through the loop, the call to `memset` looks like undefined behaviour, as you're taking the `strlen()` on uninitialized data. Try setting the `choice` to empty when you declare it: `char choice [255] = "";`. Once undefined behaviour has reared its ugly head, **all** further actions of your code are unpredicatble.

Comment: Don't do this:  `memset(choice, 0, strlen(choice));`  Instead, all you need to do is `choice[0] = '\0';`  Nothing after the `\0` matters.

Comment: Or just `*choice = 0;` which is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Since `choice` hasn't been initialized to anything, `strlen(choice)` can be returning any value between `0` and `SIZE_MAX`, which is probably causing `memset` to overwrite stuff it shouldn't.

Similarly, it may be causing problems with the first `strcmp` call against `"logout"`.

You *do* want to initialize choice to something before the first `strcmp` call; I'd recommend zeroing out the whole buffer like so:

```
char choice[255] = {0};
```

You do *not* need to clear your input buffer before reading input again - `scanf` will overwrite the existing contents with the new input.  You should probably lose the `memset` call completely.

However, if you feel you *must* zero out the buffer between inputs (and there are valid use cases for doing so, although this isn't one of them), use `sizeof choice` as the third argument to `memset`:

```
memset( choice, 0, sizeof choice );
```

This will zero out the entire `choice` array.  That way it doesn't matter if `choice` contains a properly terminated string or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using C strings and related functions like strlen, strcat, strcpy etc then `choice[0] = 0;` will do it. There is no need to set every character to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
bzero(choice, strlen(choice));
```

This should clear the data in *choice* variable